# Trouble registering secondary click on multi-touch screen

Tags: multi-touch, tablet, xinput

Having some issues trying to get Ubuntu to work on a Sony Vaio Tap 11 tablet.

Overall it's working, pen works, multitouch gestures (pinch, 4 finger show dash ..) work, however right click does not.

It uses an N-Trig multi-touch screen and pen (11", 1920x1080 - DuoSense 2 i believe, although xinput refers to it as "N-Trig DuoSense").

This is on 14.04 (fresh install, updated) but i also tried 14.10 and ubuntugnome 14.04 with no difference.

I can not get secondary click to work reliably. It's enabled in universal access, and should trigger a right click if holding down the finger for a moment.

After some testing, i think it's because of the sensitivity.
If i concentrate on holding my finger very still (with both hands) and carefully do it, i can get it to trigger on occasion, on normal use not at all.

What i believe is happening, is that the sensitivity for movement is too sensitive, so it thinks my finger is moving even though it is not - and doesn't trigger.

Was looking through the xinput settings for it, trying to change some settings but can't find a setting that affects this.

If it might be helpful, here is the output:

```
$ xinput list-props "N-trig DuoSense"
Device 'N-trig DuoSense':
Device Enabled (135):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (265): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
Device Product ID (255):    7062, 3843
Device Node (256):  "/dev/input/event17"
Evdev Axis Inversion (269): 0, 0
Evdev Axis Calibration (270):   <no items>
Evdev Axes Swap (271):  0
Axis Labels (272):  "Abs MT Position X" (540), "Abs MT Position Y" (541), "Abs MT Touch Major" (542), "Abs MT Touch Minor" (543), "Abs MT Orientation" (556), "Abs MT Tool X" (557), "Abs MT Tool Y" (558), "None" (0), "None" (0)
Button Labels (273):    "Button Unknown" (258), "Button Unknown" (258), "Button Unknown" (258), "Button Wheel Up" (141), "Button Wheel Down" (142)
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    0
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0
```

Anyone know if there is a setting i can change for this?

Or am i completely off track and something else causes this?